# What's the recommended way to interface with Apache CouchDB from a Python app?

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I want to have an instance of CouchDB running, and access it from a Python frontend. [`couchdb-python`](https://github.com/djc/couchdb-python) seems like a good option, but it's been unmaintained since 2019.

Is it a viable idea to use it nonetheless, or is there another API wrapper that's better-supported?

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/cloudant/ isn't maintained anymore either, but still works reasonably well

Comment: For anyone that finds this, I ended up just taking the hit and switching to MongoDB.